# Migration Pydantic v2 GetterDict alternative

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic, pydantic-v2

In Pydantic 1 we used the `GetterDict` function to divide the properties of a single object over multiple objects in nested form. Each objects represented a segment of related properties of the original object. for instance; all metadata related properties were grouped together in a single object, and bound as property of the root object.

Below a simple example, as input we have a single object `Source` with properties `a`, `b` and `c`. The goal is to parse these properties in a `TargetModel` object, but properties `b` and `c` are part of the `RefTargetModel` object (the `ref` property of `TargetModel`).

**Example code in Pydantic V1**

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.utils import GetterDict
from typing import Any


class NestedGetterDict(GetterDict):
    nested_fields = ['ref'] # List of fields that are nested.
    
    def get(self, key: Any, default: Any = None) -> Any:
        if key in self.nested_fields:
            return self._obj
        return super().get(key, default)


class Source:
    a = 'a'
    b = 'b'
    c = 1


class RefTargetModel(BaseModel):
    b: str
    c: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class TargetModel(BaseModel):
    a: str
    ref: RefTargetModel

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
        getter_dict = NestedGetterDict


target = TargetModel.from_orm(Source())
print(target)
# output: a='a' ref=RefTargetModel(b='b', c=1)
```

As Pydantic v2 has deprecated/removed the GetterDict functionality, we run into trouble migrating to v2. So any alternatives and suggestions on how to solve this problem in Pydantic v2 are appreciated.

note: *The GetterDict can still be used with `from pydantic.v1.utils import GetterDict`, but `ConfigDict` has no property to include it.*

On the [GitHub page of Pydantic](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/717#issuecomment-1730079433) an identical issue, but the answers were for how to handle the other way around (as also stated by the last post).

The [Pydantic migration documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/migration/) suggest that GetterDict functionality has become obsolete. So I assume there is another way.

Answer (score 0):

Child objects can actually be validated directly from the flat source. So this works:

```py
>>> RefTargetModel.model_validate(Source())
RefTargetModel(b='b', c=1)
```

Unknown attributes are just ignored. Based on this you could work with a `model_validator` like:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict, model_validator

class Source:
    a = 'a'
    b = 'b'
    c = 1


class RefTargetModel(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)
    b: str
    c: int


class TargetModel(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)
    a: str
    ref: RefTargetModel

    @model_validator(mode="before")
    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, values):
        return {"a": values.a, "ref": values}


target = TargetModel.model_validate(Source())
print(target)
```

Where the returned dictionary in `validate` now defines which fields are nested.

Maybe that helps!